# postman console error header content contains invalid characters

Tags: java, spring, rest, postman

When I hit send in Postman it shows could not get any response, error connecting to localhost and in console this is the error I got and eclipse is running.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace, code and assorted information to help you on this. A simple screenshot is not very helpful in regards to troubleshooting.

Comment: Remove the whiteSpace at the end of the Bearer token. Also remove x-roles and have a check

Comment: Thanks VelNaga when I removed the whitespace it works.

Comment: That's great...Let me post it as an answer

Comment: That is a good question. It helped me. I don't understand why it has been downvoted.

Answer (score 34):

It will work if you **remove the whitespace at the end of the bearer token**. Let us know about any issues.

Comment: @postman devs plz add a `.Trim()` to your code thanks